# python initialize nested dictionary with keys and ambiguous behavior of dict.fromkeys class method

Tags: python, dictionary

How to initialize a nested dictionary with keys.
I have looked at stack overflow related question but what I have quite not understood is dict.fromkeys functionality

For eg:
I have a list of keys

```
queue_list = ['idqueue','small','small72','medium','large','gpu','xphi']
queued_jobs = dict.fromkeys(queue_list,{}) #initializing dictionary with keys
queued_jobs['medium'][1] = 2
```

if i do this the output is:

```
queued_jobs
{'medium': {1: 2}, 'idqueue': {1: 2}, 'xphi': {1: 2}, 'large': {1: 2}, 'small72': {1: 2}, 'small': {1: 2}, 'gpu': {1: 2}}
```

Why are all keys getting assigned when I am trying to assign to only one key.

What is the solution for this

I can initialize dictionary like this:

```
queued_jobs = {}
queued_jobs['small'] = {} 
queued_jobs['medium'] = {}
....
```

But i'm looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: Don't use `dict.fromkeys` with mutable object as value, it repeats the same object. Use a dict comprehension.

Comment: Thnx . I'm wondered in what cases dict.fromkeys will come handy??

Comment: @prime130392, any immutable object will return a new object, it is with mutable objects you have a problem